# HTML/CSS Code editor text formatting hotkeys

Tags: html, css

Sorry for a topic that probably doesn't belong here, I tried Googling though and couldn't find a straight answer:

I'm looking for an simple HTML/CSS editor where I can easily and quickly set up kind of "WYSIWYG" hotkeys for text editing, like italic (ctrl+i), bold (ctrl+b), underscored text (ctrl+u), and also linebreaks and paragraph (ctrl+p) wrapping.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should do it in javascript.

Comment: @MARSHMALLOW in a text editor, or what do you mean?

Comment: @Stretchingmycompetence Are u looking for a text editor?

Comment: You probably need to give a bit more of a clue as to what this is for.  If you just want an editor with an HTML and visual view, and basic editing keys, then most online blog software will do that.  I use (free) Wordpress.  This has a quite clean HTML view of a document, and you can enter HTML in that view directly or enter regular text in the visual view.  It also handles the basic key stuff you're asking for.

Comment: @MARSHMALLOW text/code editor. Like say, Atom, Visual Studio or PHP Storm, though I couldn't find any plugins that straight up gives you hotkeys like this, or plugins where you easily can program such hotkey functionality yourself. I mean, in PHP Storm it is easy to make a template to use (forgot what they are called) though I am borrowing a PC and do not want to install something so heavy here..

Comment: @RichN, I want to press CTRL+B and wrap the selected code with <strong> tags for example.. sorry for being unclear

Comment: OK, so not Wordpress then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no editors I know that does that, but you can use AutoHotKey Scripts to do it.
First, download [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/). 
Then, create a .ahk file by `right clicking on the desktop > new > autohotkey script.`
Right click the file and press `Edit`. Copy the following code to the notepad window :

```
^Numpad1::
Send, <i></i>
return

^Numpad2::
Send, <b></b>
return

^Numpad3::
Send, <u></u>
return

^Numpad4::
Send, <br>
return

^Numpad5::
Send, <p></p>
return
```

Exit out of notepad and double click the ahk file.
Now you can use ctrl+numberpad1 to create  tags, ctrl+numberpad2 to create  tags, and so on.